# Find the number of $m$ for which holds that $\lfloor{\sqrt m}\rfloor$ divides $m$

Tags: number-theory

For a fixed $n$ find the number of $m$'s for which $\lfloor{\sqrt m}\rfloor \mid m$, for all natural numbers $m\le n$.
I have been trying to write it as $m=\lfloor{\sqrt m}\rfloor \cdot k$, where $k$ is a natural number. Putting it in the ussual floor inequalities doesn't help me much.

Comment: If you only need to find how many $n$ there are, then noting that this holds for square $n$ would seem to suffice.

Comment: @Meelo sry, I didnt write something, so I will correct it now

Comment: @Meelo: I can think of some other examples.

Comment: For exaplme: let n=100. Now we have to find all $m\le 100$ so that $\lfloor{\sqrt m}\rfloor $ divides $m$

Comment: I think what you want is [this OEIS](http://oeis.org/A204330). Take a look.

Comment: The first thing I would try is to make a spreadsheet and try all numbers up to 100 or so and see if there is a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $m$ can take all the perfect square values. Assume that $m$ is npt a perfect square.
So there exist a unique $t$ such that

$t^2<m<(t+1)^2$

assume that

$m=t^2+k$ where $k\in{\mathbb{N}}$ and $k<2t+1$

so $\lfloor\sqrt{m}\rfloor=t$

now $\lfloor\sqrt{m}\rfloor|m$

so $t|t^2+k$

so $t|k$.

But $k<2t+1$

$k=t$ or $k=2t$

Hence there are two such possible $m$ between two perfect squares i.e. $t^2+t$ and $t^2+2t$ where $t^2<m<(t+1)^2$.

Now if $n=a^2$ then obviously there are $a$ perfect square $m$ and $2(a-1)$ non perfect square.

Hence there are $3a-2$ such $m$ for $n=a^2$

now $n$ is not a perfect square. We can uniquely find $a$ such that

$a^2<n<(a+1)^2$ or in other words $\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor=a$

case-$1$

$a^2<n<a^2+a$

In this case again there would be $3a-2$ possible cases by the same logic.

case-$2$

$a^2+a\le{n<a^2+2a}$

In this case, by simple counting, there would be $3a-1$ possibilities

case-$3$

$a^2+2a\le{n}<(a+1)^2$

In this case there would be $3a$ possible $m$.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, writing out some of the actual solutions may help you to see the pattern.  I think this is one of those cases.

Consider the numbers for which $\lfloor \sqrt{m} \rfloor = 4$, say.  These are the numbers 16 through 24.  There are exactly three numbers in this range divisible by $4$: $16, 20, 24$.

Next, consider the numbers for which $\lfloor \sqrt{m} \rfloor = 5$.  These are the numbers 25 through 35.  Again, there are exactly three numbers in this range divisible by $5$: $25, 30, 35$.

You might observe, then, that for any $m$, there are always three integers evenly divisible by $m$ in the range $[m^2, (m+1)^2-1]$: $m^2$, $m^2+m$, and $m^2+2m$.

Therefore, let $p = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$.  The answer is $3p$ for $n = p^2 + 2p$; it is $3p-1$ for $n$ in the range $[p^2+p, p^2+2p-1]$; and it is $3p-2$ for $n$ in the range $[p^2, p^2+p-1]$.

Comment: Perhaps closer to $3 \sqrt{n}$ than to $3n$ but even that is not exact.

Comment: Yup.  Sorry, I misread the question slightly.  I think I've fixed the answer.